# iOS convert server time to device local time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdateformatter

I'm getting some issue to convert server time(argentina) to device local time.
here is my current code-

```
    -(NSString *)getLocalTimeStringFrom:(NSString *)sourceTime
{
    static NSDateFormatter* df = nil;
    if (df == nil)
    {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    }
    df.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";

    NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:sourceTime];
    NSTimeZone *sourceZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"ART"];//America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires (GMT-3)
    NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; //Asia/Kolkata (IST)

    [df setTimeZone: sourceZone];
     NSLog(@"sourceZone time is %@" , [df stringFromDate: d]);
    [df setTimeZone: localTimeZone];
    NSLog(@"local time is %@" , [df stringFromDate: d]);

     NSLog(@"original time string was %@" , sourceTime);
    return [df stringFromDate: d];
}
```

And here is the log if `sourceTime` string is `00:05:00`

```
    2015-09-28 15:04:24.118 DeviceP[230:17733] sourceZone time is 15:35:00
2015-09-28 15:04:24.121 DeviceP[230:17733] local time is 00:05:00
2015-09-28 15:04:33.029 DeviceP[230:17733] original time string was 00:05:00
```

**note that i'm getting local time same as the time string i pass into the method.** i looked various SO post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028804/convert-date-from-timezone-to-device-local-timezone-and-date) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030078/ios-convert-utc-timezone-to-device-local-timezone).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why declare the dateformatter as static when you are creating a new instance every time you call this method? At you issue is with the time zone.

Comment: because i'm calling this method in loop and don' want to recreate every time when my date formate would be same for all iteration. Is this a problem?

Comment: But you are creating the date formatter every time.

Comment: To make use of this static thing you could do it like static NSDateFormatter* df = nil;
   if (df == nil) { df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];}

Comment: Ok, my fault. but removing static doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your time string is in ART, you should set the timezone of date formatter before making date from the string. Means like following

```
-(NSString *)getLocalTimeStringFrom:(NSString *)sourceTime
{
    static NSDateFormatter* df = nil;
    if (!df) {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        df.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
    }

    NSTimeZone *sourceZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"ART"];
    [df setTimeZone: sourceZone];
    NSDate *ds = [df dateFromString:sourceTime];
    NSLog(@"sourceZone time is %@" , [df stringFromDate: ds]);

    NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [df setTimeZone: localTimeZone];
    NSLog(@"local time is %@" , [df stringFromDate: ds]);

    return [df stringFromDate: d];
}
```